# Why here announces the announced class agian?

Tags: c++, class, header

In a project, in one file, the "CalibHessian" has already been defined:

```
struct CalibHessian
{
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
    static int instanceCounter;

    VecC value_zero;
    VecC value_scaled;
    VecCf value_scaledf;
    VecCf value_scaledi;
    VecC value;
    VecC step;
    VecC step_backup;
    VecC value_backup;
    VecC value_minus_value_zero;

    inline ~CalibHessian() {instanceCounter--;}
    inline CalibHessian()
    {

        VecC initial_value = VecC::Zero();
        initial_value[0] = fxG[0];
        initial_value[1] = fyG[0];
        initial_value[2] = cxG[0];
        initial_value[3] = cyG[0];

        setValueScaled(initial_value);
        value_zero = value;
        value_minus_value_zero.setZero();

        instanceCounter++;
        for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            Binv[i] = B[i] = i;     // set gamma function to identity
    };


    // normal mode: use the optimized parameters everywhere!
    inline float& fxl() {return value_scaledf[0];}
    inline float& fyl() {return value_scaledf[1];}
    inline float& cxl() {return value_scaledf[2];}
    inline float& cyl() {return value_scaledf[3];}
    inline float& fxli() {return value_scaledi[0];}
    inline float& fyli() {return value_scaledi[1];}
    inline float& cxli() {return value_scaledi[2];}
    inline float& cyli() {return value_scaledi[3];}
};
```

But in another file, called "CoarseInitializer.h", it appears as:

```
namespace dso
{
struct CalibHessian;
struct FrameHessian;
...
}
```

It did nothing new to the class "CalibHessian" but just re-announced it. And it didnt include the corresponding header. But in file "CoarseInitializer.cpp" now it includes the header of "CalibHessian.h".

What Im wondering is that is this re-announcement neccessary? What is it used for?

Comment: Search for and read about *forward declarations*.

Answer (score 0):

The first file is the definition of `CalibHessian`. The header file (CoarseInitializer.h) has a declaration of `CalibHessian`.

The definition is the code that determines how a name behaves. The declaration is just a statement that the name exists. You put declarations in header files because that's how you tell files about the existence of a name in other files.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration is for the sake of the complier. This seems to be not neccessary but is preferred.

So the answer to this question is not neccessary but for compling success.

Thanks @Some programmer dude for the hint!